# UIImage.DrawInRect causes error/notification

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, drawinrect

Create a simple app, and can't do it without an error

[image: Code]

I don't really know why bg.drawInRect doesn't cause an error when player.drawInRect causing? And the problem is that image doesn't drawing/redrawing when we change coordinates

> Sep 16 22:13:16 imac-admin.lan Letalka_drawrect[804] :
>   CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error.
>   This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context 
>   and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system
>   stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this
>   problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: I've found out that this error is caused because core graphics function is called outside of drawrect, but how can i change that it will be in timer function?

Comment: Please copy your code directly in to the question instead of using a screenshot. We can't copy/paste from a screenshot ;)

Comment: Yeah, correctly, thnks for the advise, it's really helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your timer outside your `drawRect` call; [`didMoveToSuperview`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BCIIIGAB) might be a good place, but it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Then, in `timerRedraw`, call [`setNeedsDisplay()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCADHC) to trigger a re-draw.

```
var timer: NSTimer?

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    // Stop the timer if it was already running
    if timer != nil {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    // Only start the timer if the view is actually part of a view hierarchy
    if superview != nil {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "timerRedraw", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func timerRedraw() {
    x += 5
    y += 6
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

I highly recommend reading Apple's *[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156)*, it explains everything you need to know to get started with doing custom drawing in iOS.

Comment: Working best, but a little correction needs

I need to use a func setNeedsDisplayInRect(rect : CGRect)

This works setNeedsDisplayInRect(CGRectMake(x-5,y-6, rocket.size.width,rocket.size.height))

Comment: `drawRect` has a `rect` parameter which is used to determine which part of your view needs to be drawn. `setNeedsDisplayInRect(rect:)` will pass the `CGRect` you give it on to your `drawRect` function; `setNeedsDisplay()` will pass the `bounds` of your view to `drawRect` instead. Since you don't seem to be using the `rect` parameter in your `drawRect` function you must be redrawing your entire view each time it's called. `setNeedsDisplay()` seems like the more appropriate function to use in that case.

Comment: Mike, could you give me the link, where I could read how to format the code in comment, 'cause I'm trying to use <code></code> > \t but it doesn't help

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov When you add a comment, there's a little "help" link under the "Add Comment" button. Click that to see the formatting available.